# azure php app service asset folder 404 get error

Tags: php, windows, azure

We have a PHP website hosted on `Azure windows server`,
we converted `htaccess` file into `web.config` file but I think they are not proper.

> https://gardellacourier.azurewebsites.net/

please check above link,

I checked all the images are already there in the assets image folder but they are not displaying.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Also, let me know the best possible way to convert `.htaccess` file to web config.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the html page exception, this is caused by your html page requests static files(pics) from your web apps but there is no such resource provided by your webapp.

I can repro your issue on my side and it is a common issue on Azure web apps .

To solve this issue, just create a virtual directory for your `/assets` path on your webapp so that you can get static files in the URL you config. Go to "Configuration" to create a virtual directory:
[image]

The real path of my assets folder is :`D:\home\site\wwwroot\assets` , so just set the physical path as `site\wwwroot\assets`.

[image]
**Dont forget click "save" after config.**

After you create it, you can access your static files.

Result on my side :
My html:
[image]

Page display : 
[image]

Hope it helps.

web.config :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <staticContent>
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".jpg" mimeType="image/jpeg" />
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".jpg" mimeType="image/pjpeg" />
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".png" mimeType="image/png" />
     </staticContent>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Hello , @Mv Vaghela may I know is it helpful ?

Comment: Hi please have a look at attched screen shot,
I'm still getting error after adding virtual path
https://prnt.sc/ppyr00
https://prnt.sc/ppyqqs

Comment: Hi @MvVaghela , could you pls post the path of /assets folder on Azure app service ?

Comment: Hi @Stanley,
I didn't get you will please write bit more about this "could you pls post the path of /assets folder on Azure app service"

Comment: Hi @MvVaghela , as you mentioned , your static files are all in /assets folder, this folder is on your app service . So could you pls let me know the real path of it on app service ? You can use kudu to browser your web app files/folders : https://microsoft.github.io/AzureTipsAndTricks/blog/tip20.html#kudu-diagnostic-console

Comment: Hii @Stanley
please have a look at attached for the real path :https://prnt.sc/pqhics

Comment: Hi @MvVaghela , it is odd , all configs are right . I am not sure if it is due to web.config file . But you can have a try . Create a web.config file and put in /assets folder to see if it could solve your issue . The content of web.config I have appended end of  my answer .

Comment: Hii @Stenley 
please have a look at attached :https://prnt.sc/pqidgc
I added web config, still we have issue :https://gardellacourier.azurewebsites.net/

Comment: Hi @MvVaghela , I can see that there is a .ico file under your /assets folder and we can get it successfully : https://gardellacourier.azurewebsites.net/assets/favicon.ico. 
But I can not get any files under /assets/images file . Could you pls try set /assets/images as your virtual directory and set site\wwwroot\assets\images as physical path in your webapp to see if it could solve your issue ?

Comment: If it not works , I am afraid rising a support ticket from Azure portal will be a efficient way to solve your issue : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-supportability/how-to-create-azure-support-request

Comment: Okay @stanley,
Thanks for your help,I really appreciate